# Foreign key constraint (complex?)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a table that manages virtual download folders for a site.

```
CREATE TABLE `folder` (
  # id = PK
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  # folderId = self referencing FK to id
  `folderId` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  # siteId = FK to id in site table
  `siteId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
)
```

Ideally I like `siteId` to reference `id` in table `site`, but also have a compound FK `folderId, siteId` to be self referencing to `id, siteId` in table `folder`.

The reason I want this is that I want to guarantee that a child folder always belongs to the same site as the parent folder.

Is something like this possible? If so, how? And if not, do you have any other suggestions how I can guarantee this state?

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I should have mentioned this earlier: I know about InnoDB, and as a matter of fact, I'm using it already (along with foreign keys). But the question is, how will I be able to guarantee these two things:

- A record in `folder` must reference a valid `site` with `siteId`
- A record in `folder` must also be the same `siteId` as the parent record (only if it is a child of course)

I tried this so far:

```
  # this one should guarantee folder belongs to
  # a valid site (this one works of course)
  CONSTRAINT `FK_folder_site_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`siteId`)
    REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  # this one should guarantee child folder belongs to
  # the same site as parent folder (doesn't work)
  CONSTRAINT `FK_folder_folder_1`
    FOREIGN KEY `FK_folder_folder_1` (`folderId`, `siteId`)
    REFERENCES `folder` (`id`, `siteId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

So the last one doesn't work (of course?) because it seems logical that a foreign key (`siteId`) can't reference two different fields. What can you suggest to make my proposed constraints work?

Comment: I don't see why you need both the foreign keys. The second one alone should be sufficient to ensure that a record references a valid folder/site combination.

Answer (score 0):

The InnoDB storage engine supports self-referencing foreign keys, and you can use them to emulate a hierarchical structure. To declare the key, you could do something like this in your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`folderId`,`siteId`) REFERENCES `folder` (`Id`, `siteId`)
```

An important thing to remember is that this key should be `NULL`-able, so you can indicate which record(s) are the root of the tree.

Comment: @friedo: thanks, but I'm using InnoDB with foreign keys already. I've updated my question to state the problem more clearly (I hope). Would you mind taking another look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use the InnoDB storage engine

```
CREATE TABLE `folder` (
  # id = PK
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  # folderId = self referencing FK to id
  `folderId` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  # siteId = FK to id in site table
  `siteId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (folder_id, site_id) REFERENCES folder(id, site_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

It didn't test it but it should work. See [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

If you want/have to use MyISAM, of course you can do this logically the same way as you do it with the "normal" foreign key constraints.

Comment: @Felix: thanks, but I'm using InnoDB with foreign keys already. I've updated my question to state the problem more clearly (I hope). Would you mind taking another look at it? Thanks.